# what is the glade equivalent of ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry?

Tags: python, gtk3, glade

I wish to port [Ghini](http://github.com/Ghini/ghini.desktop), a Python desktop program, from GTK2 to GTK3, that is from the static `import gtk` to the dynamic `from gi import Gtk`.

Ghini is based on **glade files**, and I'm having trouble with `ComboBox` elements — with associated `Entry`.  I've searched for documentation and tutorials on the differences between Gtk2 and Gtk3 and there's quite a few, but none of the ones I found describes this particular case in any detail. The porting scripts handle the python sources, I've not found any addressing the glade files.

In the process of reducing the problem to a minimal and defined one, I've chosen [example 13](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/combobox.html) in this [Gtk tutorial](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

so I stripped down the original program to this:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class ComboBoxWindow:

    def on_name_combo_changed(self, combo):
        tree_iter = combo.get_active_iter()
        if tree_iter is not None:
            model = combo.get_model()
            row_id, name = model[tree_iter][:2]
            print("Selected: ID=%d, name=%s" % (row_id, name))
        else:
            entry = combo.get_child()
            print("Entered: %s" % entry.get_text())

    def on_country_combo_changed(self, combo):
        tree_iter = combo.get_active_iter()
        if tree_iter is not None:
            model = combo.get_model()
            country = model[tree_iter][0]
            print("Selected: country=%s" % country)

    def on_currency_combo_changed(self, combo):
        text = combo.get_active_text()
        if text is not None:
            print("Selected: currency=%s" % text)

    def __init__(self, builder):
        builder.add_from_file("/tmp/ex13.glade")
        builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.window = builder.get_object("window1")
        self.window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

    def show_all(self):
        self.window.show_all()

builder = Gtk.Builder()
win = ComboBoxWindow(builder)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

and I used Glade to put whole interface definition in this `ex13.glade` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkListStore" id="country_store">
    <columns>
      <!-- column-name gchararray1 -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
    </columns>
    <data>
      <row><col id="0" translatable="yes">Austria</col></row>
      <row><col id="0" translatable="yes">Brazil</col></row>
      <row><col id="0" translatable="yes">Belgium</col></row>
      <row><col id="0" translatable="yes">France</col></row>
      <row><col id="0" translatable="yes">Germany</col></row>
      <row><col id="0" translatable="yes">Switzerland</col></row>
      <row><col id="0" translatable="yes">United Kingdom</col></row>
      <row><col id="0" translatable="yes">United States</col></row>
      <row><col id="0" translatable="yes">Uruguay</col></row>
    </data>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkListStore" id="name_store">
    <columns>
      <!-- column-name gint1 -->
      <column type="gint"/>
      <!-- column-name gchararray1 -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>
    </columns>
    <data>
      <row>
        <col id="0">1</col>
        <col id="1" translatable="yes">Billy Bobo</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0">2</col>
        <col id="1" translatable="yes">Joey Jojo</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0">3</col>
        <col id="1" translatable="yes">Rob McRoberts</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0">11</col>
        <col id="1" translatable="yes">Billy Bob Junior</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0">12</col>
        <col id="1" translatable="yes">Sue Bob</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col id="0">31</col>
        <col id="1" translatable="yes">Xavier McRoberts</col>
      </row>
    </data>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Combobox Example</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">6</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkComboBox" id="name_combo">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="model">name_store</property>
            <property name="has_entry">True</property>
            <property name="entry_text_column">1</property>
            <signal name="changed" handler="on_name_combo_changed" swapped="no"/>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="name_renderer"/>
              <attributes>
                <attribute name="text">1</attribute>
              </attributes>
            </child>
            <child internal-child="entry">
              <object class="GtkEntry">
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="placeholder_text" translatable="yes">type, or choose</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkComboBox" id="country_combo">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="model">country_store</property>
            <property name="id_column">0</property>
            <signal name="changed" handler="on_country_combo_changed" swapped="no"/>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="country_renderer"/>
              <attributes>
                <attribute name="text">0</attribute>
              </attributes>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkComboBoxText" id="currencies_combo">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <items>
              <item translatable="yes">Euro</item>
              <item translatable="yes">US Dollars</item>
              <item translatable="yes">British Pound</item>
              <item translatable="yes">Japanese Yen</item>
              <item translatable="yes">Russian Ruble</item>
              <item translatable="yes">Mexican peso</item>
              <item translatable="yes">Swiss franc</item>
            </items>
            <signal name="changed" handler="on_currency_combo_changed" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">2</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

This, however, is not equivalent to the original example, and I don't see what I'm missing.  In particular the ComboBox with the Entry is doing this:

- the pulldown list shows the content twice

[image]

hints and criticism very welcome.

---

one hour later:

The fact that —when I set `<property name="has_entry">True</property>`— the pull down list shows two columns, this is not linked to the liststore having two columns: I've enabled it in the `country_combo` (associated to a single column liststore), and I get one empty column and one with the values from the liststore.

---

later edit: seems that the double representation is caused by the `GtkCellRendererText`, which I can safely remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, and I'm sharing it here:

first of all, I reduced the code further down, with a generic callback.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk


class ComboBoxWindow:

    def on_combo_changed(self, combo):
        tree_iter = combo.get_active_iter()
        if tree_iter is not None:
            model = combo.get_model()
            print("row: [%s]" % ', '.join("%s(%s)" % (type(i), str(i)) for i in model[tree_iter]))
        else:
            entry = combo.get_child()
            print("Entered: %s" % entry.get_text())

    def __init__(self, builder):
        import os.path
        path, name = os.path.split(__file__)
        builder.add_from_file(os.path.join(path, "ex13.glade"))
        builder.connect_signals(self)
        self.window = builder.get_object("window1")
        self.window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

    def show_all(self):
        self.window.show_all()


builder = Gtk.Builder()
win = ComboBoxWindow(builder)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

then the interface file, I also stripped it down to just one `ComboBox`, associated to a multicolumn `ListStore` model, it has an internal (id-less) `Entry`.

Pull-down happens in two different ways, one is when you type in the `Entry`, and this happens with the `Entry`'s associated `GtkEntryCompletion`, which in turn has its own `GtkCellRendererText`.

The other is the regular pull-down menu, which shows at least one column and optionally others.  In this example I'm using an extra renderer to show how it works.  I've not been able to turn off the first, default, column.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.20.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkListStore" id="epithet_store">
    <columns>
      <column type="gint"/>        <!-- column-name id -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>  <!-- column-name epithet -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>  <!-- column-name family -->
      <column type="gchararray"/>  <!-- column-name phonetic -->
    </columns>
    <data>
      <row><col id="0">0</col><col id="1">Cocos</col><col id="2">Arecaceae</col><col id="3">kukus</col></row>
      <row><col id="0">1</col><col id="1">Cheilopsis</col><col id="2">Acanthaceae</col><col id="3">kilupsis</col></row>
      <row><col id="0">2</col><col id="1">Haplanthoides</col><col id="2">Acanthaceae</col><col id="3">aplantidis</col></row>
      <row><col id="0">3</col><col id="1">Haplanthus</col><col id="2">Acanthaceae</col><col id="3">aplantus</col></row>
      <row><col id="0">4</col><col id="1">Indoneesiella</col><col id="2">Acanthaceae</col><col id="3">indunisila</col></row>
      <row><col id="0">5</col><col id="1">Ancalanthus</col><col id="2">Acanthaceae</col><col id="3">ankalantus</col></row>
    </data>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkEntryCompletion" id="epithet_entrycompletion">
    <property name="model">epithet_store</property>
    <property name="text_column">1</property>
    <property name="inline_selection">True</property>
    <property name="popup_completion">True</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="epithet_completion_renderer"/>
      <attributes>
        <attribute name="text">1</attribute>
      </attributes>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="title" translatable="yes">Combobox Example</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">6</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkComboBox" id="epithet_combo">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="model">epithet_store</property>
            <property name="has_entry">True</property>
            <property name="entry_text_column">1</property>
            <property name="id_column">0</property>
            <signal name="changed" handler="on_combo_changed" swapped="no"/>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="epithet_renderer"/>
              <attributes>
                <attribute name="text">2</attribute>
              </attributes>
            </child>
            <child internal-child="entry">
              <object class="GtkEntry">
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="completion">epithet_entrycompletion</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">4</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

---

If I wasn't interested in keeping the information in a ListStore model, and only needed to handle text and have an entry, the following also works, in the sense that lets me type, and distinguish the case "it was chosen"/"it was typed":

```
      <object class="GtkComboBoxText">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="has_entry">True</property>
        <items>
          <item id="1" translatable="yes">Aitano</item>
          <item id="2" translatable="yes">Aniello</item>
          <item id="3" translatable="yes">Antonio</item>
          <item id="4" translatable="yes">Fiorentino</item>
          <item id="5" translatable="yes">Peppino</item>
          <item id="6" translatable="yes">Strato</item>
        </items>
        <signal name="changed" handler="on_combo_changed" swapped="no"/>
        <child internal-child="entry">
          <object class="GtkEntry">
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="placeholder_text" translatable="yes">type, or choose</property>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
```

the associated callback is the same as in the above complete solution

Answer (score 0):

So far I understand what you are doing is: for a test of a new application migrating from gtk2 to gtk3, you overtook http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/combobox.html and try to make it differently (not with a script only but with a reduced script and with a separate GLADE file). Have you tested http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/combobox.html as it is? (personally I would not rely 100% on code in WWW; but make the test of it before you make your modified script). I personally used combo till now only as passive window and never connected with signals.

Comment: if it wasn't clear from the text: I am trying to understand how to make a glade file define a ComboBox that I can use in a Gtk3 program.

Comment: download the glade file from here: https://github.com/f4iteightiz/UWR_simulator  There are few comboboxes.

Comment: have you tested any of the things you are mentioning? your hint contains ComboBoxText elements, not ComboBox with model. I did test all that I posted here, and you seem to put that in doubt. I'm not going to downvote you since it looks like you're quite new here, but please review how this site works, and check the difference between a comment, and a fully fledged self-contained answer. cheers, and enjoy staying in this community.